# How to configure preferred ciphers in Paramiko library

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

In Paramiko library, I want to specify preferred ciphers (to disable the less secure ones).

I have tried to overwrite the transport preferred ciphers like this

```
paramiko.Transport._preferred_ciphers = (aes128-cbc,...)
```

This is working fine and I am able to overwrite and disable the ciphers.

But I am facing a warning *"W0212 Access to a protected member _preferred_ciphers of a client class"* while using it.

Is there any other way to restrict the ciphers used in Paramiko?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Transport.get_security_options()` to get an instance of [`SecurityOptions` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.SecurityOptions).

And use its `ciphers` property as a correct way to set the underlying `Transport._preferred_ciphers`.

To be able to do this, you need to use low-level [`Transport` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html) for your SSH connection implementation, not the commonly used high-level [`SSHClient` class](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html).

*When using `Transport` class, make sure you do not forget to set `Transport.connect` `hostkey` parameter to validate the host key. The `Transport` does not validate the key automatically (contrary to `SSHClient`). Forgetting to do that is a security flaw.*

---

The `SSHClient` object creates a `Transport` class object under the covers, but it gives you no way to modify or call methods on that object before it uses it to attempt a connection.

If you want to keep using the high-level `SSHClient`, then setting `_preferred_ciphers` is the only way.